# Is it possible to delete messages older than 14 days? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am making a bot for a friend. He was wondering if I could make a command to delete messages in a channel. I discovered there is a limit at 100 messages, and they must be newer than 14 days. Is it possible to delete messages older than 14 days? Here's my code:

```
const client = new Discord.Client;

const PREFIX = '!';

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot-ul merge!');
});

client.on('message', msg => {

    let args = msg.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ');

    if (args[0] === 'delete') {
        if (!args[1]) {
            msg.reply('trebuie sa imi spui cate mesaje sa sterg!');
        } else {
            msg.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
        }
    }
});

client.login('token');
```

Comment: You cannot `bulkDelete` them, but you can manually delete them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete messages over 14 days old, but I have a tip for you:

Don't use `args[1]` for the amount, use `parseInt(args[1])` as it prevents errors.